# NativeScript android BetterVideoPlayer implement

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to implement [BetterVideoPlayer](https://github.com/halilozercan/BetterVideoPlayer/tree/51d862019ce3750d58b6360a07279bf78d51e89c) (`implementation 'com.github.halilozercan:BetterVideoPlayer:1.2.alpha1'`) for NativeScript Android. So, in an Angular project I have created separate component like this:

```
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/core/view";

declare var com, android;

export class BetterPlayer extends View {

    public mediaPlayer;

    public createNativeView(): any {

        const nativeView = new android.widget.FrameLayout(this._context);

        nativeView.addView(this._openVideo());

        // or return this._openVideo(); // still not working..

        return nativeView;
    }



    public _openVideo() {
        let url = android.net.Uri.parse("http://jzvd.nathen.cn/c6e3dc12a1154626b3476d9bf3bd7266/6b56c5f0dc31428083757a45764763b0-5287d2089db37e62345123a1be272f8b.mp4");

        this.mediaPlayer = new com.halilibo.bettervideoplayer.BetterVideoPlayer(this._context);

        console.dir(this.mediaPlayer);

        this.mediaPlayer.setSource(url);
        this.mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        this.mediaPlayer.setHideControlsOnPlay(true);

        return this.mediaPlayer;
    }
}
```

Then from component I have registered it using `registerElement`

```
registerElement("BetterPlayer", () => BetterPlayer);
```

HTML:

```
<BetterPlayer height="200"></BetterPlayer>
```

But the problem is, it isn't showing the player. Only showing a black area. In where I did mistake? Please give me advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I know why do you add your Player to `FrameLayout`, it works bit different than other NativeScript layouts.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to add it directly but didn't work either. So, I tried to follow from demo but none is working.

Comment: Do you have the plugin on Github?

Comment: Not actually, I am using nativescript angular project directly. If you want then I can create quickly.

Comment: @Manoj, I have created a git repo for your testing. You can have a look from here: https://github.com/jibon57/BetterVideoPlayer       
`src/app/item/items.component.html
src/app/item/items.component.ts
src/app/item/items.component.ts
src/app/item/betterVideoPlayer.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BetterVideoPlayer creates the actual media player within at `onFinishInflate()`, is a method called only when a View element is initiated via Android XML, programatic creation like you do in {N} won't trigger this method. So you could simply do `this.mediaPlayer.onFinishInflate();` to force creating the media player and it should work, I was able to watch the video on device once I did.

Comment: I can't add subtitle using `setCaptions` method. I am getting error. Will you please have a look the repo again? Thanks

Comment: I am getting this error: `System.err: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.halilibo.bettervideoplayer.subtitle.CaptionsView.setCaptionsSource(android.net.Uri, com.halilibo.bettervideoplayer.subtitle.CaptionsView$CMime)' on a null object reference`

Comment: I don't see setCaptionsSource call in your code, did you update github?

Comment: Yes, I did it already: https://github.com/jibon57/BetterVideoPlayer/commit/2934eda60811ad95b25d3a52e0b76e2a7e903b75

Comment: I am using version: 1.2.alpha1 from [this commit](https://github.com/halilozercan/BetterVideoPlayer/tree/51d862019ce3750d58b6360a07279bf78d51e89c#captions) &